# Как запустить react из отдельных файлов?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel

У меня вопрос, как сделать так чтобы появился скрипт который подключает собранный файл от webpack. Это pug

```
include layout
sctipt(type='text/babel' src='/client/bundle.js')
#content
```

В webpack

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + "/public/js/AuthForm.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/public/client")
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

В .babelrc

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ]
}
```

И в самом файле AuthForm.js простенький код

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Только когда я все собрал

```
C:\OpenServer\domains\trainingPortal>npx webpack --config webpack.config.js
npx: installed 1 in 1.823s
Path must be a string. Received undefined
C:\OpenServer\domains\trainingPortal\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
Hash: 9a12974da47514bba93f
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 1248ms
    Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
bundle.js  727 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
  [14] ./public/js/AuthForm.js 418 bytes {0} [built]
    + 26 hidden modules
```

То у меня не выходит надпись Hello world, Хотя по логике моей она должна выйти

Comment: у вас не собралось из-за неправильного пути, попробуйте взять его в кавычки

Comment: @СашаБоричевский Да вроде бы все нормально собралось. А откуда знаете что неправильно собралось?

Comment: @СашаБоричевский Если имеет значение, то у меня node js. На чистом коде без сервака, я сделал нормально

Comment: А почему `type='text/babel'` ? Вы же через бабель-лоадер его прогоняете, там обычный js на выходе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat .babelrc
{
  ....
  "presets": [
    "react", <- это раз 
    "es2015", 
    "stage-0"
  ]
}

$ cat package.json
{
  ....
  "devDependencies": {
    ....
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",  <- это два
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    ....
  }
}
```